# Terraform import selects by default an AWS profile different from the one set in the provider code block

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

So I want to start importing the existing infrastructure from an AWS account and I have this simple code in a `main.tf` file:

```
provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials_file = "$HOME/.aws/credentials"
  profile                 = "profile_I_want"
  region                  = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "my_cluster" {
  # name = "my-cluster"
}
```

And my credentials file for AWS has two profiles + the default one set:

```
[default]
aws_secret_access_key = secretkey2
aws_access_key_id = accesskey2
[another_profile]
aws_secret_access_key = secretkey1
aws_access_key_id = accesskey1
[profile_I_want]
aws_secret_access_key = secretkey2
aws_access_key_id = accesskey2
```

Note: `another_profile` and `profile_I_want` correspond to different AWS accounts.

These are the versions I'm working with:

```
Terraform v0.12.28
+ provider.aws v2.70.0
```

And when I execute `terraform import aws_ecs_service.my_service my-service`, the next error shows up:

```
aws_ecs_cluster.my_cluster: Refreshing state... [id=arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:another_profile_ID:cluster/my-cluster]

Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object
```

*Notice the `another_profile_ID` arn.*

So these are my questions:

1. Terraform is selecting by default `another_profile` at one point and I don't know how to change it. Can I set and import infrastructure from the `profile_I_want` account?
2. Can I import infrastructure when there's no previous `.tfstate` file in the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, at least in my case, it seems `terraform import` takes the value of the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY`, so I just changed the value for those two variables while I'll work on this project.